# Get value or return null

Tags: c#, return

I have a method that searches for a value in an html document, if an item is found (("settingsings")), then the value is returned.
But if the element is not found (("settings")), then the loop exits.
I want if the item is not found then CurrentProfileDLS is set to null

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify(string CurrentProfileDLS)
{
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in elmC)
    {
        if (elm.Id == "DLSProf")
        {
            if (elm.InnerText.Contains("settings"))
            {
                CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");
            }
        }
    }
    return CurrentProfileDLS;
}
```

I tried it, but the CurrentProfileDLS variable is not set to null:

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify(string CurrentProfileDLS)
{
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in elmC)
    {
        if (elm.Id == "DLSProf")
        {
            if (elm.InnerText.Contains("settings"))
            {
                CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");
            }
            return CurrentProfileDLS;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You only want to return if you actually set the variable.

Comment: Why are you passing in `(string CurrentProfileDLS)`? You're not using it anywhere. It's not a `ref` or `out` parameter, so you're not returning its value, and strings are immutable so changing the value in the method won't change  the calling method's variable. It's entirely redundant.

Comment: There are correct answers to this question. But I see a code-smell here: I suppose CurrentProfileDLS is a class field. So this method is violating Command-Query Principle. I suggest do a little refactor, it will be more readable and you wont have these kind of problems with it anymore.

Comment: @John is right. if you want it to set to null. you have to do something like this: `CurrentProfileDLS = CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify(CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify(CurrentProfileDLS))` but as @AliDoustkani suggests, you might be better off refactoring

Answer (score 2):

The `CurrentProfileDLS` doesn't seem to even be needed.  Why not just return directly based on the results?

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify()
{
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    var elm = elmC.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == "DLSProf" && e.InnerText.Contains("Settings"));

    return elm?.GetAttribute("value");
}
```

Your original post lets the loop continue on finding a match, making the behavior akin to 'last one in wins', so if that is still needed, you can change this line simply to:

```
var elm = elmC.LastOrDefault(e => e.Id == "DLSProf" && e.InnerText.Contains("Settings"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set `CurrentProfileDLS` initially to null.

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify(string CurrentProfileDLS)
{
    CurrentProfileDLS = null;
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in elmC)
    {
        if (elm.Id == "DLSProf")
        {
            if (elm.InnerText.Contains("settings"))
            {
                CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CurrentProfileDLS;
}
```

I do not understand the purpose of the parameter `CurrentProfileDLS`. I suggest you remove it if it has no other purpose other than storing the value from `CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");`.

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify()
{
    string CurrentProfileDLS = null;
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in elmC)
    {
        if (elm.Id == "DLSProf")
        {
            if (elm.InnerText.Contains("settings"))
            {
                CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CurrentProfileDLS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a value to be set (or nulled) but not using the `Out` modifier on the parameter. Without knowing exactly why you're passing in `CurrentProfileDLS` I would suggest a mild modification of

```
private string CopyProfileDLS_Intercept_AddPhone_Unify()
{
    string CurrentProfileDLS = null;
    var elmC = web_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement elm in elmC)
    {
        if (elm.Id == "DLSProf")
        {
            if (elm.InnerText.Contains("settings"))
            {
                CurrentProfileDLS = elm.GetAttribute("value");
            }
        }
    }
    return CurrentProfileDLS;
}
```

This way you are initializing the field as null and returning it at the end, regardless of if it gets overridden with `elm.GetAttribute("value");`.